# Which is more basic: oxaziridine or diaziridine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

Which is more basic: oxaziridine or diaziridine?

[image: oxaziridine and diaziridine]

Oxaziridine's got one nitrogen and one oxygen as heteroatoms, while in diaziridine there are both nitrogens.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question per se. However, since we have a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) policy, it would be nice if you could elaborate a bit more and add your thoughts or reasoning (besides stating the fact how many atoms are there) in order to prevent the question from being closed.